# Как сделать автоматическое монтирование расшаренной по сети папки с полными правами на изменение?

Tags: linux, unix, сеть, права

Сейчас в `/etc/fstab` прописано:

```
//192.168.19.90/ExampleFolder /mnt/exampleFolder cifs  auto,user,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,umask=000,username=john,password=pa$s 0 0
```

В итоге получается:

```
root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 12599296 2012-12-06 13:35 exampleFolder
```

А надо чтобы было `drwxrwxrwx`. Как изменить?

Comment: Если на удаленной машине расшаривает папку windows, то монтировать её надо при помощи samba, все-таки. Например, [тут][1] обсуждают данную проблему. Хоть топик и устарел, но суть понятна: монтировать командой smbmount, насчет настройки fstab я не уверен.

Если же там unix, то для решения данной проблемы я использую [NFS][2]. Настройка для неё несложная. Настройка для автомонтирования зависит от дистрибутива.


  [1]: http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1404-how-to-mount-a-windows-share-with-smbmount/
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System

Comment: Мрак и ужас. NFC-то зачем? (Ещё одна файловая система). А что касается smbmount, так ТС её и использует, правда неявно -- см. буковки cifs

Comment: Смотреть параметры uid, gid, mode и umask (uid и gid -- кто смонтировал).

Comment: Мое упущение, согласен. NFS привел просто для примера, в юниксах она смотрится логично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понимаю, то достаточно на удаленной и на локальной машине сделать:

```
chmod 777 exampleFolder
```

Comment: Когда делаю root@ubuntusrv:/mnt# chmod 777 exampleFolder, то получаю ошибку chmod: changing permissions of `exampleFolder': Permission denied. На удаленную машину доступа нет. Внутри /mnt/exampleFolder я могу делать изменения, но веб-приложение на сервере не может потому что ему надо чтобы на папку /mnt/exampleFolder права были 777.
UPD: Еще я думаю что удаленная машина работает под виндой и там chmod же не сделаешь.

Comment: Опять же если я правильно все понял: на Linux сделайте  sudo chmod 777 /mnt/exampleFolder
Эта команда даст право на любые действия для всех на linux. В удаленной же машине ничего не изменится и все (пользователи, демоны и тд) с Linux будут писать в удаленную машину с теми правами с которые есть у пользователя username=john,password=pa$s

Comment: На sudo chmod 777 /mnt/exampleFolder выдает: chmod: changing permissions of `exampleFolder/': Permission denied. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: хз) возможно стоит сначала отмонтировать, сменить права доступа для папки и потом обратно примотировать...